# How do I evaluate a graph to know where my node can make the most beneficial connections?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I want to learn more about graph and node algorithms and how to improve the health of the graph. The graph I am thinking about would be something akin to a hub and spoke layout. The improvements I'd like to make would be:

1. Segment the graph into clusters and find clusters that are not well connected to each other, than improve this by making various connections between the clusters
2. Find desirable endpoints to the graph (hubs that send/receive a lot of traffic) and create more efficient routes between them and other hubs, and/or them and clusters of spokes/nodes that are many hops away from them
3. Evaluate the “centrality” of a node

What are some methods for evaluating the best connections I can make from a node I control to improve the overall connectivity of this (loosely defined) graph?

Any information about graphs, algorithms, or distributed computing that might be useful is welcome (for example I understand Dijkstra's algo for finding the shortest path). I'm happy to add more detail, not trying to be obscure, I'm just in a don't know what I don't know state.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you measure "the overall connectivity of the graph"?

Comment: @ravenspoint good question. This is a new area for me so I'll have to get some more fundamentals under my belt to better define my objectives. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you mean by improving the overall connectivity of a graph.

For example:

1. The graph might have two or more disconnected parts.  The connectivity will be improved if your node has a connection to one node in each disconnected part.
2. You might want to measure the longest path.  Then your node should have connections to the start and end nodes, reducing the longest path to 2 hops.

... The possibilities are endless, unless you clarify what you mean.

Comment: thanks, I added some more detail to hopefully narrow the question down. If it behoves you, feel free to ask more so I can further refine.